# Styling controls: How to overwrite the styles in different 'VisualState's (PointerOver, Pressed, ...)

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

How does one handle hover states and so on?

One could overwrite a brush like `SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush` for a `Button`:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="White" />
```

If any other control uses that brush, it also takes this value, which is not desired. The other option I found is to overwrite the default style:

```xml
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button -->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here I would change the values in `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. But what is if the default styling changes in an upcoming version of Windows?

Currently I see no other way than overwriting the default style. Perhaps one could overwrite some events and set e.g. the border color there. But I think there are not always all events available and you would have to write your custom button everytime.

It looks somehow wrong to me to overwrite a complete style for changing only one value. How do you handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, changing the complete template (not style) is the most used scenario.

There are different points to consider here:

- You want all of your controls to have a consistent layout across your application.

So my first option would be to define a new **theme** for your application and indeed overwrite the `SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush` and other `ThemeResource` resources required to accomplish your new branding.

- You only want a single control to change layout.

If for some valid reason you don't want all controls using the `ThemeResource` to change to your new theme, you will have to overwrite the complete control template (as the template is one block and thus an **all or nothing**). There is no need to overwrite all other property setters (like Foreground, Background, Padding, ... in your example).

*If you're very lucky, the property you're trying to change is a templated property and you can simply use a single property setter to fix your layout.*

The downside with this approach is indeed that future versions of the SDK can change the template of a given control. An example of this are the GridView/GridViewItem styles between Windows 8/8.1 and 10. So far there has mostly been a backward compatibility on styles, meaning your app will continue to work but might not be in line with the latest layout guidelines or miss some performance improvements. It's therefor 'best practice' to **re-apply custom layout changes** on the newest templates (if time permits).

A 'dirty' solution is 'hacking' into the Visual Tree to change properties at runtime (based on events, ...). But this won't prevent you from possible breaking changes on future SDK updates either, so I wouldn't even consider this as a valid option.

- Going with custom controls

The final approach is going with a custom control, define your own template (again the same problem with newer SDK versions) or use the default template and  override [`OnApplyTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate) and tweak the property you'd like to change by getting it from the Visual Tree. But same remarks apply here that a future SDK version might drop the control/state in your tree and break your code.

Conclusion: either option you choose, there's a possibility future SDK versions will break your implementation.

Comment: I've some `Button`s in a `ListView`. If I'd define a new theme, also these buttons would get the style (but they shouldn't get it). So this is currently no option for me. I haven't worked with control templates yet, but it seems to be a good option and I have to look into that more. Thanks for giving more insight into this.